# Can this sorting algorithm's time complexity be further optimized?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, time, time-complexity

```
import random
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

array = list(range(1, 11))
random.shuffle(array) 

new_array = []

minimal_num = 0

while len(new_array) < len(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] - minimal_num == 1:
            minimal_num = array[i]
            new_array.append(minimal_num)

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

'''real-case scenario would involve lists of 100000+ elements. I also tried through pure functions, but it turned out similar.'''

Comment: Try running your algorithm on the array `[2, 4, 3]`. Be ready to kill the process.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the numbers in the array you want to sort are unique from 1 to N. You could just return new array `[1, 2, 3, ..., N]` and you don't need to do any sorting.
You could do something like this:

```
return list(range(1, 11))
```

If the numbers in the array you want to sort are not from 1 to N then your code won't work either.
In this case you can have a look at [merge sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/) or [quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) algorithms